# Python3 How do i use an element from a function in another function

Tags: python, function, dictionary, request

I have a file which looks like this :

```
OG_100000: V_bacterium_v|198260291 O_bacterium_v|391222558 O_terrae_v|182414991
```

and i did this function :

```
def readGroupFile(groupFileName):
dict_gene_taxonomy = {}
fh = open(groupFileName,"r")

for line in fh:
    liste = line.split(": ")
    groupName = liste[0]
    genesAsString = liste[1]
    dict_taxon = {}
    liste_gene = genesAsString.split()

    for item in liste_gene:
        taxonomy_gene = item.split("|")
        taxonomy = taxonomy_gene[0]
        geneId   = taxonomy_gene[1]                         

        if taxonomy in dict_taxon:
            listeCorrespondantATaxonomy = dict_taxon[taxonomy]
            listeCorrespondantATaxonomy.append(geneId)
        else:
            dict_taxon[taxonomy] = []
            dict_taxon[taxonomy].append(geneId)

    dict_gene_taxonomy[groupName] = dict_taxon
fh.close()
return dict_gene_taxonomy
```

I did this function to make dictionaries and split element in each dictionary to be able to reach only the element after the pipe("|"), called geneId.

Then i made a function to create a Post Request on a internet database with these geneID. I'm not gonna link the whole function because it works properly when i manually add the geneId in the function's line :

```
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(getPost("391222558"))
```

considering the fact that "391222558" is one geneId from group file, but i need to replace these numbers by every "geneId" in my readGroupFile function.
i can't write :

```
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(getPost(geneId))
```

because i'm calling an element in a readGroupFile which is not defined outside this function.
So how can i reach all the "geneId" in my readGroupFile function to add this parameter in getPost(...) so it can work for every geneId in my group file ??

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are creating only local variables , and those are deleted when the function end.

so you got couple of options:

the first one is define the geneid as a global variable , all you got to do is just:

```
     global geneid
     def readGroupfile():
     global geneid
```

you will have to define him once not in a function and then whenever you use it just write global and his name,and it will make him global variable.
your secend options is to do the same with your dict , that also contain this variable.
i hope i helped you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm gonna try this and see if it works.

Comment: i did what you suggested and i get :

 global geneId = taxonomy_gene[1]       
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax, the ^  point on the =

Comment: u need to write it just once in the beginning of the function and every time u use it just write geneid with out the global , but at the top u need to write global geneid like that: 
            code:
            global geneid
            def readGroupfile():
            global geneid
            geneid = somthing
some how it doesn't set the code as a code so imagine that every definition is different line

Comment: did it work ? if it didn't u may contact me in private i would love to help you.

Comment: it didn't work but i probably misunderstood how to write it, but i found an other way to get what i needed. By the way thank you for your time and your lovely answers :)